# Rails 7 help DRYing out image attachments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Bear with me, I am new to posting and Rails so sorry if I mess up phrasing!!

I am working on a Rails app with many similar models. Each view has a `_form.html.haml` partial that differs in content but contains similar components, such as buttons to submit, delete, etc.  Every model has_many_attached photos, and in the form you can add or delete photos.  The haml for deleting photos looks like this, where variable is replaced with whatever view `_form.html.haml` is in:

```
.gallery#form
  - @VARIABLE.photo.each_with_index do |image, index|
    .overlay-container
      .img-square{ :style => "background-image: url(#{rails_blob_url(photo(@VARIABLE, index))})", :alt => "Photo of #{image}" }
      = link_to("Delete", delete_image_attachment_VARIABLE_url(image), method: :delete, class: 'button delete overlay')
```

To make the delete work on each photo, this code is in each controller:

```
  def delete_image_attachment
    @photo = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    @photo.purge
    redirect_back fallback_location: @VARIABLE
    flash[:success] = 'Photo was successfully deleted.'
  end
```

And `routes.rb` has this chunk of code for each model:

```
  resources :VARIABLE do
    member do
      delete :delete_image_attachment
    end
  end
```

However, I have about a dozen models I need to do this on. My goal is to bring the gallery into a new partial, since it will be used in every _form regardless of the other content.  However, the delete function (though the same for every controller) is tied to the controller/routes.rb of each model.

There must be some way of DRYing this functionality into a couple files instead of copy-pasting for each model, but my Google searches have not turned up anything.  So, any guidance or better Rails convention is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the structure properly, it sounds like you would want to do something like the following:

### Create a top-level controller that handles deleting images

- This could be used by any page.
- This would require the following query parameters:

  - `id` the photo's ID to delete by.
  - `redirect` where to redirect the user after the action is completed.

### Routes

Now there will only be 1 route to handle the controller above.

### Create a reusable partial

For rendering a collection of images with a redirect url that allows you to set the following state for the partial:

- `photos` a collection of images to render.
- `redirect_url` this is passed as a query parameter to the centralized delete image controller.

### Thoughts & Mocked Examples

This should be able to DRY up your implementation. Currently the only thing I see that couples the view with the deletion is the redirect URL. By abstracting that out and moving that essentially to a parameter for the partial will allow for re-use and flexibility.

You've already identified your coupling via `@VARIABLE`, here's a quick mock of how I would expect it to end up looking like:

#### Partial Template

```
.gallery#form
  - @photos.each_with_index do |image, index|
    .overlay-container
      .img-square{ :style => "background-image: url(#{rails_blob_url(photo(@VARIABLE, index))})", :alt => "Photo of #{image}" }
      = link_to("Delete", delete_image_attachment_url(image, redirect: @redirect_url), method: :delete, class: 'button delete overlay')
```

Ths would require: `photos`, and `redirect_url`
So make sure to set `@photos` and `@redirect_url` on the consuming controller.

##### Example with instance properties to access in the template

```
@photos = GET_PHOTOS_HERE
@redirect_url = 'some-redirect-path'
render partial: 'photos_partial'
```

##### Example with locals parameter for the template

```
photos = GET_PHOTOS_HERE
render partial: 'photos_partial', locals: { photos: photos, redirect: 'some-redirect-path' }`
```

**Note**: You may need to change how you access the local variables in the template.

> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

#### Controller

```
  def delete_image_attachment
    @photo = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    @photo.purge
    redirect_back fallback_location: params[:redirect]
    flash[:success] = 'Photo was successfully deleted.'
  end
```

#### Routes

Here you would only have the single route for deleting any image attachment, and point at the single controller above.

```
delete 'resources/image_attachment/:id', to: 'resources#delete_image_attachment'
```

**Note**: Replace "resources" with whatever your controller name is, or the scoping/naming you would like.

**PS**: It's been a while since I've done Rails so I'm not completely certain on the accuracy or your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! This was a great template.  It took a second to figure out how to get all the plumbing (routes) to work together, but creating a new ImageAttachmentController then manually setting up a route for delete in the routes.rb seemed to work well.  After I could call the new method in the html file, the DRYing out the html by making a new partial was easy.